# Is there a Windows Live Messenger Connect v5 C# SDK?

Tags: sdk, connect, windows-live-messenger

Is there a Windows Live Messenger Connect v5 C# SDK? something like [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165649/live-messenger-over-xmpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows Live SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264574.aspx)

[Windows Live Messenger Connect Developer Guide, Version 5.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243641.aspx)